# Как ввести строку неизвестной длины с консоли на с++ без использования string?

Tags: c++, строки, ввод

Нужно написать программу,которая читает с консоли строку(которая может быть большого размера) и избавляется от определенных букв.Как это сделать без использования string?

Comment: Можете реализовать свой string)

Comment: @ПавелЕриков так стоит делать если нужно запуулить строки и сделать стаснение строк через указатели.

Comment: Без использования  string, а куда читать  не рассказали. Просто читайте пропуская не нужные символы. if(character == symboll) cin.ignore();

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку в С++ такое *не нужно*, решение C'шное:

```
char * readLine()
{
    int size = 0, capacity = 16, ch;
    char * buf = malloc(sizeof(char)*capacity);
    for(ch = fgetc(stdin); ch != EOF && ch != '\n'; ch = fgetc(stdin))
    {
        if (size >= capacity - 1)
        {
            capacity *= 2;
            char * tmp = realloc(buf,sizeof(char)*capacity);
            if (tmp == NULL) { buf[size] = 0; return buf; }
            buf = tmp;
        }
        buf[size++] = ch;
    }
    buf[size] = 0;
    return buf;
}
```

Разжевывать не надо? :)

Comment: можно было бы и new/delete использовать. да, оно было бы сложнее, но все же

Comment: @KoVadim Да не было бы оно сложнее, по большому счету. Одна лишняя строчка...

Comment: Но если уже сильно-сильно придираться, то в данном коде смешано две вещи - работа с памятью и пользовательский ввод. Но для начинающих сойдет

Comment: GNU аналог [getline()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) оставляет в строке `\n` и возвращает ее длину.

Comment: @avp Не вижу в условии требования писать аналог `getline`..

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать массив равный длине строки и хранить в каждой ячейке acsii коды вводимого символа

UPD: если возможно, используй вектора https://code-live.ru/post/cpp-vector/#_1

если нет, можешь попробовать для добавления каждого нового элемента динамически создавать новый массив с n+1 элементов (где n - кол-ов элементов предыдущего массива) https://ravesli.com/urok-86-dinamicheskie-massivy/#toc-3

Comment: если бы длина строки была известна...

Comment: @KoVadim, ну можно же руками все делать  при нехватке

Comment: можно. Но вот хотелось бы это в ответе увидеть.

Comment: @KoVadim, обновил ответ, надеюсь поможет

Comment: как по мне, то он где то на 0.2-0.3 бала.